# Where find a free GPS coordinates database?

Tags: mysql, database, gps, coordinates

For my app need to have a list of mayor worldwide cities with relative GPS coordinates for proximity search, anyone know how is possible to find a db of this type? (not API)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202092/where-can-i-find-free-and-open-data) somewhere in the answers you may drill down to what you want.